# Cannot Read .xlsx file

Tags: excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I am having trouble reading .xlsx files downloaded from an email inbox. I've tried reading through pandas, xlrd and openpyxl. I am able to open the file in excel, and if I manually save the file as a .csv or an excel workbook it will read the file.

```
openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
IndexError: list index out of range

xlrd.open_workbook(path)
XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjkIi.png)

```
pd.read_excel(path)
XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook
```

Full Error:
pd.read_excel(path)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5424c3c557fd> in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_excel(path)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    176                 else:
    177                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 178             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    179         return wrapper
    180     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    176                 else:
    177                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 178             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    179         return wrapper
    180     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, **kwds)
    305 
    306     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 307         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    308 
    309     return io.parse(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, io, **kwds)
    392             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    393         elif isinstance(self._io, compat.string_types):
--> 394             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
    395         else:
    396             raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    143         if 'content.xml' in component_names:
    144             raise XLRDError('Openoffice.org ODS file; not supported')
--> 145         raise XLRDError('ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook')
    146 
    147     from . import book

XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your excel file. I think the error might be due a column with numbers in it, is read as a `str`. Use converters while reading excel file - `pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',converters={ "Num_col" : str })`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sumanth! I tried using converters and also tried using dtype=object and dtype=str but am still getting the error. I removed any sensitive data from the file but this is essentially what it looks like

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data, like first 3-5 rows ?

Comment: @Sumanth I added a picture of how the file looks, I can send a copy with the first few rows if that would be useful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the errors you're seeing: the exception on its own isn't much help.

Comment: @Charlie-- I have updated it to include the full traceback.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue, I'm having the exact same issue on a similar report.

Comment: @Eumcoz The solution I found was using Libreoffice. This is the thread I found that helped me https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/12084/how-to-convert-documents-to-pdf-on-osx/.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out its due to the report being an older XML based .xls file.  The xlrd library will not add support for that file since they see it as an XML file.  Going to switch report formats.